# why join doesn't work on a list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, join

```
','.join([number for number in range(2000,3201) if number%7 == 0 and number%5 != 0])
```

doesn't work.

However,

```
l=[]
for i in range(2000, 3201):
    if (i%7==0) and (i%5!=0):
        l.append(str(i))

','.join(l)
```

works.
Aren't two things in the parenthesis of type list ?

Comment: The `.join` expects items to be `string`. In your comprehension list use `str(number)` instead of `number`.

Comment: Your second code wouldn't work either if you used `i` in place of `str(i)`.

Comment: @chepner I didn't see that ! tks !

Comment: _doesn't work._ What does that mean, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`join` expects `string` types, you will have to modify your list function like this:

```py
','.join([str(number) for number in range(2000,3201) if number%7 == 0 and number%5 != 0])
```

Comment: @SayandipDutta The brackets are recommended. `join` works more efficiently if it is given a list, rather than being forced to iterate an arbitrary iterable twice (once to allocate space for the resulting string, again to actually build the string). (Or to be more precise, the list comprehension is more efficient at building the list than `join` can be with an arbitrary iterable.)

Comment: @chepner did not know that, will delete.

Comment: @chepner is this applicable for other functions that take iterable, for example `sum` or is this specifically for strings?

Comment: Specific to `join`, for the most part. The reason `join` is preferred over something like `s1 + s2 + s3` is that it creates *one* string object in memory and initializes it using `s1` et al, rather than compute `s1 + s2`, then computing `that_result + s3`. But since `str`s are immutable, you can't create that one string object without first knowing the total length of all the strings being joined. `sum`, on the other hand, will simply call `+` multiple times to adds its arguments. (That's one reason `sum` is hard-coded to reject an iterable of strings as its argument.)